# How to backup a set of queries in Cognos?

Tags: backup, database-backups, cognos

I have a folder containing a set of queries in Cognos. I have tried backing up an individual query by exporting it to notepad. But if I want to back up all the queries in a folder at a time, what would be the best way? I would appreciate your help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem in Cognos instances where you have multiple report authors creating BI content.

I would suggest taking a look at MotioCI - its designed to do automated version control for content in your Cognos instance.   This means anytime someone makes a change to Cognos content, you'll know who did it and exactly what they changed.

It also gives you the ability to look at the revision history on Cognos objects (allowing you to revert back to an earlier version if desired).

http://www.motio.com/products/ci/versionControl.do

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have Admin access, I'm not sure of a way to save all queries in a folder. As a work-around, I've found this method of saving local copies faster than notepad. When you follow these steps you'll be able to open and save Cognos 8 xml files locally. I find this helpful when developing new reports.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.8.4.0.doc/ug_cr_rptstd_id29382cr_rptstd_modrep_open_save_report_l.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out a thirdparty tool such as MetaManager which could give you archive/recovery plus it looks like many other tools.

http://www.bspsoftware.com/Products/ImplementationBasedSoftware/IntegratedArchiveService/tabid/203/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools like the above people who have answered thus I haven't used any so I cannot say.

When I work in a Cognos project I usually create a "branch" (actually a folder in Cognos Connection) and export on a daily basis. The resulting files are backed up.

Although I wouldn't recommend to manually copy-paste the XML of the reports (time consuming taks and could lead to errors), back in 2007 there was this big project where those XML files saved our arses.